# Nested SOQL not working in the test class

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, unit-test, query

I have a test class testing a trigger and I associated an opportunity to an account. However, I ran the SOQL statement

```
List<Account> accountList SELECT ... (SELECT ..., AccountId FROM Opportunities) FROM Account
```

where the ... are standard and custom fields on the account and opportunity. I ran the statement in my test class but when I try to debug the response, I don't see a column listed as Opportunities.

Plus, I tried

```
accountList[0].Opportunities
```

and I couldn't get any opportunities from it.

I ran the statement in a production environment and it worked but this statement doesn't work in a test method.

Does anyone have an idea why?

EDITED 1:

Thanks for the initial responses! I forgot to mention that I have created test Accounts and test Opportunities. They are not querying from the actual org.

Comment: Possibly [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)? Take a look at some of the other questions on this site for more details.

Comment: I edited the question to say that I have previously created test data. Not sure why even with the test data that I still can't see it...

Answer (score 4):

You should not see the org data in Test classes. Before querying this, You must make sure that You are inserting opportunity related to the account in the the test class.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create your own data when running tests. Something like:

```
Account parent = new Account(/*required fields*/);
insert parent;

Opportunity record = new Opportunity(/*required fields*/);
record.AccountId = parent.Id;
insert record;
```

Then your query will work. See also:

- [Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm)

  > Starting with Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 24.0 and later, test methods don’t have access by default to pre-existing data in the organization, such as standard objects, custom objects, and custom settings data, and can only access data that they create.
- [Creating Test Data for Apex Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_data)
- [Getting Started with Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro)

  > By default, Apex tests don’t have access to pre-existing data in the org, except for access to setup and metadata objects, such as the User or Profile objects. Set up test data for your tests. Creating test data makes your tests more robust and prevents failures that are caused by missing or changed data in the org. You can create test data directly in your test method, or by using a utility test class as you’ll find out later.
- [An Introduction to Apex Code Test Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)
- [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: I previously created test data. I'm not sure why I still can't see it though...

Comment: @akcorp2003 So you get the `Account` record back from your query but no `Opportunity` records? Are you setting `AccountId` on them?

Comment: I get the account record back no problem and I set the accountId on the opportunity.